# Why we use getState() in select statement of query while retriving data in Joomla?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, model

I'm learning Joomla Extension development and overriding `getListQuery()` method of a model that extends `JModelList`.

Now the problem is that we can retrieve a list of data from database using following which is working fine:

```
$db = $this->getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('id,title,state,company')->from($db->quoteName('#__books'));
```

But my ebook use following statement

```
$query->select(
$this->getState('list.select','a.id, a.title,' .'a.state, a.company'));
```

> I understand the `getState()` method but why does the ebook author use
>   `getState()` in select statement? What is the purpose of
>   using this and where the 'list.select' property will be defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using state in the select statement allows external extensions to use your method individually and to get different sets of data from it.

A good example is `mod_articles_news` module [helper](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/modules/mod_articles_news/helper.php) which sets the fields for selection from the Articles Model:

```
// Get an instance of the generic articles model
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Articles', 'ContentModel', array('ignore_request' => true));

... 

$model->setState('list.select', 'a.fulltext, a.id, a.title, a.alias, a.introtext, a.state, a.catid, a.created, a.created_by, a.created_by_alias,' .
' a.modified, a.modified_by, a.publish_up, a.publish_down, a.images, a.urls, a.attribs, a.metadata, a.metakey, a.metadesc, a.access,' .
' a.hits, a.featured, a.language');

...

$items = $model->getItems();
```

Comment: oh thanks a lot now i get it, the getState() will try to find the value of list.select but it will find nothing when component is executing so this will return 'a.title, a.name'  as default values. and in the time of modules we will set models 'list.select' state value as what we need and we will get our result...! thanks again

Comment: Yes you are right.